# Active Isolated Stretches

Tags: stretching

I purchased [The Wharton Stretch Book](https://www.abebooks.com/book-search/title/whartons-stretch-book-featuring/author/wharton-jim/?ref_=ps_ms_267691761&cm_mmc=msn-_-comus_dsa-_-naa-_-naa&msclkid=39c12609177714b88ac043b39313d446) which advocates [active isolated stretching](https://www.stretchingusa.com/active-isolated-stretching/) [AIS] and it seems great, I can't find a ton of information online about it though.

Are there any critiques of AIS or downsides I should know about? It seems like static stretching is [widely perceived as harmful](https://archive.nytimes.com/well.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/04/03/reasons-not-to-stretch/) to those who know about the topic, but finding comparisons or discussion of stretching outside seems severely anecdotal, and there isn't even a Wikpiedia page for AIS.

Comment: Did you read the article on stretching being harmful? What they are saying is that static stretching before an active event can hinder performance, which has been widely known in the exercise community for some time. It's not saying that static stretching is harmful overall, just not recommended before active exercise. AIS has some dubious claims (Avoids the stretch reflex, which occurs in a few hundredths of a second), and looks like a slightly different version of ballistic stretching.